# Will passing *this in a function parameter cause a memory leak if the parameter takes a reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, this, memory-leaks

I have a function that takes a reference

```
void TestFunction(Class &instance);
```

and when I call the Test function I pass *this into the parameter.

Ex:

```
TestFunction(*this);
```

Will this cause a memory leak?

Comment: Not by itself. A bit more context would probably help.

Answer (score 4):

No, it will not leak.  No additional memory is being allocated that needs to be freed. You are simply passing a reference to an existing object already in memory.